# Not getting image over the submit button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to get an image over my button, but I am not getting it. Here is what I have been doing.

```
<span id="schedule_button">
     <input type="submit" value="submit" 
             style="background-image:url(scheduler_button.gif); 
             font-size:0px; width:270 px; height:66 px" />
</span>
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Try removing the space before `px` `width:270px; height:66px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

### **First**:

**Update:** As King King brings to notice in comments, it's only the second problem which causes your troubles.

The `input` element is by default inline, so when you set font-size to 0px, it takes only that much space as required to display the value, which is very little,

Thus, it is necessary to set its `display` to `block`.

You might want to google "Inline vs Block elements."

### **Second**:

You need to remove the space in `width:270 px` and `height:66 px`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/5c7KU/1/)**

#### CSS:

```
input {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/270x66');
    font-size:0px;
    width:270px;
    height:66px
}
```

Comment: looks like the `input` button element is a special element, it is not a container element so `display:inline` or `display:block` does not matter, it still works in both cases http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5c7KU/1/

Comment: @KingKing New discovery! Thanks for bringing to my notice. Editing my answer to reflect the fact.

Comment: My button has round edges. What I am getting now is an oval inside a rectangle. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: @saplingPro I am not getting any oval (in the fiddle). Perhaps, your `span` might be having some CSS rules. Please share them also.

Comment: I meant I am getting the button image inside the rectangle. It looks like http://s27.postimg.org/97p2iunwj/Capture.jpg

Comment: @saplingPro I urge to share the CSS rules of your span also. Another idea: Try setting the `border-radius` of the `span` to `10%` then maybe `15%` or `5%` until it fits your needs.

Comment: There are no css rules for span

Comment: @saplingPro try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5c7KU/5/ In fact you don't need this image as background, you can render the similar image using gradient background.